# Alternativa para o uso do UNION no mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, union

Bom dia, estou fazendo a soma dos elementos de uma coluna (que chamei de MinhaColuna) em função de outra, chamada "turno". Há três valores para turno, portanto preciso que o código de retorne três valores distintos de soma. Para isso, estou usando a função `UNION` do `mysql`. Ele me retorna os valores sem problemas. Contudo, ao fazer a conexão em `PHP`, o resultado do turno 3 some, sendo devolvido apenas os dois primeiros valores. Seria o `UNION`o causador do problema no `PHP`? Existe alguma alternativa para o uso do mesmo ou solução para este caso?

```
SELECT sum(MinhaColuna) as 'Soma1' from TabelaX where turno='Um' UNION 
SELECT sum(MinhaColuna) as 'Soma2' from TabelaX where turno='Dois' UNION 
SELECT sum(MinhaColuna) as 'Soma3' from TabelaX where turno='Três'
```

Comment: Tendou usar o `UNION ALL` ? Caso valores coincidirem, ele pode não estar trazendo.

Comment: Tentei sim, mas o erro persiste.

Comment: Poste o código de como está gerando a tabela... porque se o seu select está ok, então o problema é no php

Comment: Acredito que o problema está no seu código PHP e não na sua query ou seu banco. Se você acha que o problema é do UNION tenta fazer essa query com GroupBy: SELECT sum(MinhaColuna), turno from TabelaX where turno in ('Um', 'Dois', 'Três') group by turno

Answer (score 2):

Seu SELECT deve retornar o resultado correto, os dados disponíveis podem causar esse comportamento ou há algo errado no código PHP. Acho que dados disponíveis é que causam o comportamento que você vê, último parágrafo da resposta comenta este caso.

Apesar disso, uma maneira geralmente melhor de fazer seria usar GROUP BY:

```
SELECT turno, SUM(MinhaColuna) as Soma FROM TabelaX 
WHERE turno IN ('Um', 'Dois', 'Três') GROUP BY turno;
```

O WHERE é para limitar aos turnos desejados, porém não lembro se o "IN" usa índice nas comparações. Se o WHERE for removido, as somas para todos os turnos serão retornadas, talvez seja o resultado desejado.

Esta query vai retornar as somas de cada turno, porém, se não houver nenhum registro em algum turno, ele não aparecerá (mesmo comportamento da outra query neste caso).